# XCode won't set my iPhone as active scheme

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, linker

I only wanted to see how my app behaves on first launch, so I deleted it from my iPhone(iOS 4.3), now XCode would show `"iOS device"` as the active scheme, and when I manually select my iPhone from the list, I get an error (scrolling from the top of the screen) saying `Could not launch “project1”` `No such file or directory (/Users/portal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project1-cfjhjgezzcapwoadaivpptyywptu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/project1.app/project`

What might have happened?
I CAN install the app on my iPod (iOS 6) though.

Answer (score 2):

Delete your derived data directory for this project, by doing the following steps:

Close the project, but keep Xcode opened.  Go to "Organizer" -> Projects.  On the left side, select your project and then click the "Delete" button for the derived data.

Once it's gone, open up the project, run a Product -> Clean and try to redeploy.

If the 'delete' button is greyed out, click on the little arrow to the right of the derived directory path (this will open up Finder).  Shut down Xcode, and then send that directory to the trash.  Restart Xcode, run a Product -> Clean on the project and try to redeploy.

Comment: Derived data is located in /Users/portal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData and basically contains all other projects. Is that ok?

Comment: You can safely delete a subdirectory of Derived Data.  If it helps, I had made a blog entry on this, with some screen shots:  http://www.intertech.com/Blog/Post/Xcode-45-Could-Not-Launch.aspx

Comment: the derived data's "Delete" button is grayed out for some reason

Comment: after trying and retrying again, Near the "Derived Data", all it says in gray is "Derived Data includes index, build output and logs", the delete button is still gray

Comment: Follow the steps I wrote in the edited answer. That will allow you to bypass the greyed out button and remove it from the finder. If you would like to see screenshots for this process, click the link that I posted in the comments above.

Comment: If you don't see a path there, I'd shut down Xcode, navigate to the derived data directory, and delete all of its subdirectories that start with my project name. Restart Xcode, clean, and redeploy.

Comment: ok I did the following steps: went to another project, clicked the little arrow, and saw my projects derived data directory in Finder. closed XCode, moved the derived directory to the trash, restarted XCode,  Clean project, tried to deploy, and no go! I think the problem has to do with XCode not setting my iPhone as active in the active scheme.

Comment: Shut down XCode before directory removal

Comment: If you don't have any snapshots you need to worry about with this project (because this step will remove all snapshots as well), go back to that same screen, do a secondary click on the project name, and select "Remove from Organizer..." Clean and Redeploy.

Comment: Will the project come back to the organizer after I redeploy?

Comment: Yes, but the deleted snapshots won't (if you took any).

Comment: Sorry Ted, I'm out of ideas on this one!

Comment: It has to do something with the device not showing by default on the active scheme I am almost completely positive about that

Comment: for the heads up, the Delete button isn't grayed out anymore :)

Comment: Something prevents my iPhone from showing on the active scheme and I think this is on the way to the solution