# How to restore my project wisely

Tags: ios, xcode

So, it started as a simple test, where I had to delete my app from my iPhone (iOS4.3) just to check how the app behaves on a first run. (I am developing to support down to iOS4.3).

After the deletion, I wasn't able to run the app on my iPhone for some reason. The `"Active Scheme"` would show `iOS Device`, although I could manually select my own device from the list, the project wouldn't set my device by default. XCode would drop a message from the top saying:

```
Could not launch “project1” No such file or directory  
(/Users/portal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project1-  
cfjhjgezzcapwoadaivpptyywptu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/project1.app/project
```

I went through this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13460875/xcode-wont-set-my-iphone-as-active-scheme) (**EDIT**: Therefore, restarting XCode, iPhone doing clean project, hard resetting my iPhone) but this didn't change anything, except I can now delete the Derived data in Organizer.

I have a working backup at hand though. Thing is it is a bit outdated as I made many changes to the project. I can run the backed up project, and it seems sane as good.

Now my question is how can I merge the files back into the sane project? The XCode project itself has changed a bit, frameworks were put in as well as some settings.

I tried to simply copy the changed files into the old project, but all I get is a SIGABRT upon the first run. I did a FileMerge look, and saw that for some reason my projectAppDelegate.m is non existant in the PBXBuild section of the .xcodeproj file. which I didn't touch. seems like a mess here.

How can I merge the new project to the old one correctly?

Comment: May I recommend Git or SVN so that this never happens again?

Comment: have you tried performing a full clean? when you delete your project from the iphone it should not affect your project on xcode at all. before doing weird stuff, clean the project, re-start the iphone. re-start xcode. Build the project and see if you have the same problem.